# H1 tag and hr not positioning correctly in div surrounded by divs CODE ERROR

Tags: html, header, alignment

i have a h1 header in-between divs containing javascript popup images (placeholders). i want it to be aligned the same as the "websites" h1 tag, to the left with a hr to the right. but the hr goes through the text and the text is centered in the page.
the only css applied is this

```
.port_title {
text-indent:35px;
position:relative;
 top: 35px;
}


.port_hr { width:550px;
style="color: #333; background-color: #333; height: 1px;
}
```

you can view the html here
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/portfolio.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
h1 {
    background: #fff; // or whatever is your bg-color
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

h1+hr {
    margin-top: -0.6em;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/cTMXa/